# Is it possible to "master out" in the Japanese PhD system?

Tags: phd, japan

So my son just got accepted for the PhD program in physics at the University of Tokyo. If he decides that for any reason he needs to leave is he able to get just a masters after 2 years or does he need to complete what he signed up for.  They are paying for the entire program, including housing/food and expenses.  We are proud and very happy for him, just exploring all possible outcomes because 5 years in a country he has never visited in a big commitment.

Comment: Interesting question. I updated the title -- we can't advise on a specific university's policies (you would have to ask them), but questions about the Japanese system generally are on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably something only someone from the specific program can answer. In fact, your son probably can in a few months once there, with the graduate handbook in hand, and in contact with the people who make decision.

So have some patience. At the point where he's in a PhD program, your son is also an adult who will find his own way -- let him explore his options himself.

Comment: I think it's reasonable to ask about this _before_ accepting the offer; after moving to Tokyo and declining any other offers, it is likely too late. (Agree that this is for the son to figure out, or not, however).